# Using MySQL select in Java as String

Tags: java, mysql

I have problem with executing query in my Java program. Here is the code:

```
String selected=offersList.getSelectedValue();
String sql="SELECT * from outcoming_offers where about='"+selected+"'";
pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs=pst.executeQuery();
```

And when there is single quotes in 'selected' - it is giving me an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near.....

So I understand why there is error but I am wondering how to make this work. Are there any other ways except concat()?

Comment: Why don't you use parameter `String sql="SELECT * from outcoming_offers where about= ?";
ps.setString(1, selected);`

Answer (score 2):

It's always better approach is to use prepared statements instead of raw SQL string concatenation.

From your example you should write prepared query like below (parameter to pass are replaced with question marks):

```
String sql="SELECT * from outcoming_offers where about=?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.preparedStatement(sql);
```

And then just inject parameter values and execute query:

```
ps.setString(1, selected);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Thanks to this approach you don't have to deal with SQL query string and single quotes, which is very often error-prone and also (very important) your code is not expose to SQL Injection attacks.

More info in documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [Prepared Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) but not passing the required parameter as you should.
 Change the statement to this:

```
String sql="SELECT * from outcoming_offers where about=?";
```

and then pass the parameter:

```
pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, selected);
```

This way you set `selected` as the 1st parameter of the Prepared Statement.
Now you can execute the query:

```
rs=pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem consider accepting it.